# SetPolyFillmode ALTERNET and WINDING

Tags: windows, win32gui

Currently i am reading  programming windows 5/ed .

the doubt is regarding  petzold chapter 5 page  169 - 170.

In  SetPolyFillmode  I have not understood how the polygon filling modes  ALTERNET & WINDING work and the rules behind them.  I read description from the book but it is quite complex can anyone give a simple explanation.??

Thank you

kanade

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs here. I think the description is fairly adequate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145080(v=vs.85).aspx